# Does Ignite require blanket export (ALL-UNNAMED) of java module packages even for Ignite client nodes (thick or thin)

Tags: java, ignite, java-17, gridgain

I see in the ignite [docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java#running-ignite-with-java-11-or-later) that running ignite with Java 11 & specifically with Java 17 requires a bunch of `--add-opens` to blanket export (`ALL-UNNAMED`) a bunch of java module packages.

Its not clear if this requirement applies only to server nodes or to client nodes (thick & thin) aswell.

Does anyone know if this is needed for client nodes aswell & if so is there a difference with thin client vs thick?

EDIT (18-Jan-24):

Add to the above, if one looks at the [Gridgain documentation](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/getting-started/quick-start/java#running-gridgain-with-java-11-or-later), it points to a much smaller set of blanket exports than the Ignite one.

Secondly, not having these with Java 11, didn't appear to cause any issues with Ignite thick client nodes.

Thanks

Comment: You can see that ignite.sh has these flags for any running node. So I'm guessing there is no difference between server and client fat nodes.

Comment: @AndreiAleksandrov You are right, there is no difference for thick clients. For thin clients it turns out these are not needed altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who might run into this issue, I got the answer from the team

These JVM export directives are needed for clients aswell, but with the below exception.

Using thin client would NOT necessitate these JVM export directives that the use of thick client requires.

So this is one more reason to switch to thin client if one's use cases don't require the full thick client functionality.

Thanks